# How to add the condition such that the elements of the group $G$ are in normal form on GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gap

Let $G:=F/[x^{a}*y^{-b}*z^{-c}, y^{q}*x^{-p}*z^{-r},z^{k}*x^{-v}*y^{-w}]$ be abelian group by given relations
$m:=[[a,b,c],[p,q,r],[v,w,k]]$ and given restrictions of elements of $m$.
How to add the condition such that the elements of the group $G$ are in normal form in the following code?

```
F:=FreeAbelianGroup(3); 
x:=F.1;; y:=F.2;; z:=F.3;; 
n:= 145;; a:=1;; b:=8;; c:=4;; p;; q:=6;; 
for r in [2..10] do 
  for v in [11..16]do 
    for w in [2..10]do 
      for k in [2..20]do 
        total:=[];; 
        G:=F/[x^a*y^-b*z^-c, y^xq*x^-p*z^-r,z^k*x^-v*y^-w]; 
        m:=[[a,b,c],[p,q,r],[v,w,k]];
        if IsCyclic(G) and Determinant(m) mod n=0 then 
          Print(m," size ", Size(G),"\n"); 
          Add(total,Mt); 
        fi; 
      od;
    od;
  od;
od;
```

I tried with

```
List(L,p->PolynomialReducedRemainder(p,gb,MonomialGrlexOrdering()));
```

when there is given the presentation of $G$. But in this case the relations are given by $a,b,c$ ... and do not know how to be considered that elements of $G$ must be in normal ordering.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `m:=[m:=[[a,b,c],[p,q,r],[v,w,k]]]` is not a valid GAP syntax, please fix, perhaps a typo duplicating `m:=`? Also, I've edited the code to use indentation, makes it more readable.

Comment: Thanx a lot @Olexandr

Comment: What is the normal form you use?

Comment: Dear professor @ahulpke  when there are given relations of G I got it in the format I need in this way                                                                                                                        
```
P:=PolynomialRing(Rationals,["x","y","z"]); 

var:=IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(P);; 

x:=var[1];;y:=var[2];;z:=var[3];; 

LoadPackage("singular"); 

GBASIS:=SINGULARGBASIS;; 

gb:=ReducedGroebnerBasis(relations,MonomialGrlexOrdering()); 

List(L,p->PolynomialReducedRemainder(p,gb,MonomialGrlexOrdering()));                                     ```

Comment: Are you talking about a group or a polynomial ideal?

Comment: About e group dear professor @ahulpke

Comment: If it is a group, Why do you use a polynomial ring?

Comment: I used polynomial ring because it help me to have the elements of G in that normal format I need. My problem is to add this condition on the code such that is given a general presentation of $G$ with some restriction described above.